# How to access Offline Maps in Android

Tags: android, maps, kml, arcgis, shapefile

I was given a task where i need to build an offline map i have shape file and a kml file..

I found something about kml where i need to parse the data and overlay the data on the maps.but it should be done from scratch.**If there any tutorial Please do help me for kml**.

or

**IS there any easy way to store the maps offline and use it in android. i see lot of things like tpk,.map etc**

**please do help** i am struck with this from abt a week and dint find any clue how to do it..

Answer (score 0):

tpk is basically doing the map with tile packages concept, whereas the other option involves using sqlite format compact cache. for more details, you can consult arcgis library at
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/Welcome_to_the_ArcGIS_Server_10_Help/009300000004000000/

and also this is for OSMdroid library
http://www.haakseth.com/?p=30. hope it will help you